# WCF Service browser

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

What is the best way to achieve something like the [SQL Server Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2%28VS.80%29.aspx) but for WCF services running on the local network?

I don't necessarily want to be able to browse for any and all WCF services, but rather for a service which has been coded to be browse-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy in WCF 4.0, which includes [new WS-Discovery features](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2009/02/13/using-ws-discovery-in-wcf-4-0.aspx).  You'd have to hand-roll your own version of this for the current releases of WCF, I believe.

Comment: Exactly what I was after (presuming it works as advertised!)... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of doing this myself, and Will's response clarifies that I may have to do this my hacky way.

My server app has a restricted range of port numbers on TCP/IP (say: 8000-8080). A brutal solution would be to set off 5 or so threads at a time, each thread trying a different port until it got a response on a relatively short timeout.